# How can we use mysql's limits with iBatis generally?

Tags: mysql, ibatis

I use iBatis 2.3.4

I have the following query:

```
<select id="getUserList" resultMap="userListResult">
    SELECT
            id,
            name,
            login,
            email
    FROM
          users
</select>
```

And when I need to provide paging I use:

```
sqlMap.queryForList("base.getUserList", startPosition, numItems);
```

Then iBatis generates query without limit, and skips extra data during fetching.
I belive that work with limits is more faster.

How can we push iBatis to use LIMIT generally? Is It possible?
May be we can describe some dialect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with passing the limit,offset as parameters ?
For example (in Postgresql, I think Mysql is similar) :

```
<select id="getUserList" resultMap="userListResult">
    SELECT  ...
    FROM  users
    LIMIT #limit:INTEGER# OFFSET #offset:INTEGER#
</select>
```

Then in your dao you could code:

```
  Map params = new HashMap();
  params.put("limit",10);
  params.put("offset",100);
  res = sqlMap.queryForList("base.getUserList", params);
```

Comment: How would you implement paging on this scenario, if you want to show and search results only page by page?

Comment: Your DAO just knows how to treat limit/offset. The upper layer must compute them to do pagination as it wishes, that has nothing to do with iBatis. See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412059/how-to-implement-general-pagination

Comment: Hi, is this for version 2 or 3? My inline (#) parameters are always translated to ? with this code.

Comment: @Zeratul: unless I'm mistaking your problem: inline parameters are normally translated to '?', they are parameters in preparedStaments

Comment: i solved it, hash (inline) params can only be used for values (WHERE id = #id#), for direct dynamic sql they need to be wrapped in dollar signs: LIMIT $limit$ OFFSET $offset$