# Best practices of implementing pagination in Doctrine2 ORM on repository level

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, pagination

I'm aware of [Doctrine's Paginator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html), but it works on DQL level. What I'm looking for is a way to implement pagination on repository level.

- The first way I see is to incapsulate pagination within the repo:

  - by making all of it's methods accept two additional arguments, `$offset` and `$limit`, or
  - by implementing `setOffset` and `setLimit` methods within my repo that would affect all of it's `find...` methods (which is not good due to the `DefaultRepositoryFactory` implementation, [which behaves as a Singleton Factory](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php#L42)).
- The other way is to make a `ResultBuilder` class as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412059/how-to-implement-general-pagination). I don't really like this approach because it works on a prefetched result set, which makes extra data retrieval even with Doctrine's lazy-loading.

Which other approaches to the subject exist, and which approach would be the best for a Doctrine2 ORM user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution I've discovered is to make a corresponding Filter (using LIMIT statement), as described in [official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html), and apply that filter to a repo before using it's query methods (including custom).